# Which api retured results using Typescript

Tags: typescript

1. I am calling two webapi from Typescript, I want to know which api has returned results first using typescipt

2.I want to show that first results using angular html.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Irrespective of which api returning resulsts first , I showing one api data first by default. Later by clicking button I am pushing the data of other api to show the data altogether on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, please consider editing it.

That said, for your first question, you may be able to leverage the [Promise.race() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) like so:

```
// Your web api request methods
function requestA(): Promise<string> { ... }
function requestB(): Promise<string> { ... }

Promise.race([requestA(), requestB()]).then(winner => {
    console.log(winner);
    // Make use of the first result here
});
```

If you do also care about the second result, you can use a combination of both `race` and `all`

```
// Your web api request methods
function requestA(): Promise<string> { ... }
function requestB(): Promise<string> { ... }

const requests = [requestA(), requestB()];

Promise.race(requests).then(winner => {
    console.log(winner);
    // Make use of the first result here
});

Promise.all(requests).then(results => {
    results.forEach(console.log);
    // Make use of all results here
    // Note: This will also contain the already seen winner
});
```

This can then scale to any number of requests where you care about the first one that comes back immediately but also care later on about the others.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of bloating the comments with code. It's incredibly hard to parse code like this.

Comment: Is this Javascript or TypeScript . I am using typescript. I am looking for samples in Typescript. I can able to understand your answer. But I need it in typescript. The using subscribe keyword in my function and using variable to assign data from wep api and using that variable in html  file of angular to show the data. Thanks.

Comment: My answer is TypeScript. Again, please stop posting code into comments, as it is not legible that way. If you want me to take a look, edit your original question and format the code there.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the results that I expected. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Hi, I have one extent end questions related to this topic. If the first winner has zero records I want to show the records from second winner and same like that If second winner has also zero records I want to go for third winner. Can you please help on this.

Comment: Given that this is a new quesiton, please post a new question with the current code and what you are expecting / having trouble with and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I posted new question with title 

TypeScript Promise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107231/typescript-promise/51107482#51107482