# TypeScript Promise

Tags: typescript

I have below line of code and I am getting results.

```
Promise.race(this.custs).then(Winner=> {
  this.Winner= Winner;      
});
```

I want to move on to next webApI if first Web api on the race has zero records.

In other words I want to get results from the winner who has records.

this.custs array variable has n number of webapi's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "winner" is not simply the first Promise to resolve, you will need to move beyond using `Promise.race`. I'm not certain the exact structure of how you are triggering the async requests, but it should hopefully be easy to map the following on to what you have:

```
const winner = null;

const customerIds: string[] = ['1', '2', '3', /* ... */];

const customers: Promise<Customer>[] = customerIds.map(
  id => loadCustomer(id).then(customer => {
    if (!winner && customer.records.length > 0) {
      winner = customer;
      // We have a winner, do whatever else you need to with it
  }
);
```

All we've done here is check for each customer that is loaded, if we already have a winner and if the loaded customer has any records. If we don't have a winner yet, and this customer has records, they are the winner.

Then at any point, if you also care about knowing when all customers are loaded, you can simply:

```
Promise.all(customers);
```

Comment: I have to use promise.Race functionality to see which api's getting result first and at the same time I have to use web api's  which is getting result with records.

Comment: The above will still resolve in the order that the api's come back, emulating the behavior of Promise.race.

Comment: In my case (this.custs) is the list of web api's that I am passing, I didn't see variable for web api's in your code.

Comment: I don't know what loadCustomer stands for in your code. Can you please explain , do I have to declare that I a variable.